# joda-time-2.9.9.jar in project cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, jodatime

`Whenever I tried to run spring boot application that shows some buildpath error.
That Java Date and time jar already there in the classpath.

**Archive for required library: 'C:/Users/GSM/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/2.9.9/joda-time-2.9.9.jar' in project 'discovery-server' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file**

Comment: Have you checked to make sure the copy you have actually is, at the least, a valid zip file?

Comment: If you are using maven, You can try Deleting the JAR mentioned

Go to eclipse, right click the project and select run as->maven-install. It will download the right jar file.

Comment: Yes, I do. I think some version mismatch. Let me check.

Comment: By the way, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode). While currently maintained, the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are obviously using Maven. Check if the file joda-time-2.9.9.jar in your local Maven repository is a valid archive by opening the file with any archive programm (p.ex. WinZip). If this gives you an error, delete the file in your local repository and rebuild your project. Maven will reload the file from Maven central (or whatever you have configured as remote Maven repository)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a corrupted artifact in your local maven repository. You could try to remove the directory from the repository and letting maven re-download it on the next build.

On windows, given the path in your question, you could run

rd c:\Users\GSM.m2\repository\joda-time\joda-time\2.9.9 /s

Maven should re-download it on the next build